# How to manipulate the time of a date using PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to manipulate the time of a date using PL/SQL?

Below is my code.

```
declare
    venter date := '2021-01-05' ;
    vexit date := '2021-01-05';
    vseq number := 2;
begin

    while venter < sysdate loop

        venter := venter+1;
        venter := to_date(round(dbms_random.value(40,59)), 'mi');
        venter := to_date(round(dbms_random.value(0,59)), 'ss');
        vexit := to_date(round(dbms_random.value(0,20)), 'mi');
        vexit := to_date(round(dbms_random.value(0,59)), 'ss');
        if mod(to_char(venter, 'd'), 7) + 1 in (6, 7) then 
            continue;
        end if;
       insert into tblattend values (vseq, venter, vexit, 'normal', null, '1');
        vseq := vseq + 1;

    end loop;
end;
```

I want to randomly set the minutes and seconds in the `venter`, and if it's a weekend, use continue to exit, and insert statement a value when the above expression is executed.

However, I got currently stuck in an infinite loop.

How can we solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About indefinite loop: *days* don't change in your code. `SYSDATE` will eventually change and in a matter of days your `IF` statement will be satisfied. However, saying that you

> use continue to exit

is a little bit strange; I'd use `exit` to *exit*. Wouldn't you?

So - yes, it is indefinite (at least, looks like that to me). If you leave it alone long enough, you'll run out of disk space eventually (running all those inserts) and then it'll fail.

Examine contents of `tblattend`  table and see what you're inserting. Then fix code you wrote. How? I don't know, depends on what you want to do. Maybe set a counter and exit the loop if you insert more than e.g. 100 rows.